# Using Persian Datetimepicker in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datetimepicker

I am trying to use a `persian datetimepicker` inside my project .I am using MVC4.

So i found a link `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248909/persian-calender-in-mvc-asp-net` and i decided to implement this .

I added some `css and js` file to my project as you can see here (i added to my layout page):

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/js-persian-cal.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/js-persian-cal.min.js")"></script>
```

So i created a model as you can see here :

```
 namespace MvcApplication2.Models
{
    public class DTpicker
    {
         public string name { set;get;}
         public DateTime datetime { set; get; }
    }
}
```

I create a view `create view` as you can see here :

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.DTpicker

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "create";
}

<h2>create</h2>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var objCal1 = new AMIB.persianCalendar('pcal1'); </script>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>DTpicker</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.datetime)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.datetime, new { @id = "pcal1", @class = "pdate" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.datetime)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

As you can see i added some extra code to my datetime as you can see here :

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.datetime, new { @id = "pcal1", @class = "pdate" })
```

I added this part of code to the create view as you saw above :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
            var objCal1 = new AMIB.persianCalendar('pcal1'); </script>
```

So but where is the problem ,when i run my application the datetimepicker doesn't work .I saw the view source of the page using browser and my datetime input have a syntax like this :

```
   <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="datetime">datetime</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field datetime must be a date." data-val-required="The datetime field is required." id="datetime" name="datetime" type="datetime" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="datetime" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
```

As you know the id should be `pcal1` but as you can see the id is `id="datetime"` why ?

best regards .

any ideas will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EditorFor` doesn't support passing HTML attributes. So the object you're passing isn't doing anything. (Actually, it is doing *something* just not what you expect. It will set keys in `ViewData` with those values, e.g. `ViewData["id"] = "pcal1"`.) The id is being set to `datetime` because that's the name of the property you're creating an editor for.

So, you have two options:

1. Don't use `EditorFor` but something like `TextBoxFor` instead. That will allow you pass HTML attributes to be rendered on the input:

   ```
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.datetime, new { type="datetime", @id = "pcal1", @class = "pdate" })
   ```
2. Create a editor template to be used for `DateTime` properties:

   **Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\DateTime.cshtml**

   ```
   @{
       var htmlAttributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(ViewData["htmlAttributes"] ?? new {});
       htmlAttributes["type"] = "datetime";
       htmlAttributes["class"] = htmlAttributes["class"] == null
                                     ? "pdate"
                                     : "pdate " + htmlAttributes["class"];
   }

   @Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, htmlAttributes)
   ```

   Then in your view:

   ```
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.datetime, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "pcal1" } })
   ```

   Notice that the `pdate` class is being added by the template, so you don't have to pass it manually. I'm assuming this is what your JavaScript attaches to, so you'd want this class to always be present on inputs for `DateTime` properties. Also, note the syntax for the `EditorFor` call. Instead of passing an anonymous object consisting of `id`, you need to pass one consisting of `htmlAttributes`, which then itself has an `id`. This is because, again, `EditorFor` just sets the values in `ViewData`.